# What is the use of the classes 'wide' and 'extrapretty' within a fieldset?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Within a fieldset i've added the classes wide and extrapretty like so:

```
@admin.register(PeerReviewProject)
class PeerReviewProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    date_hierarchy = 'creation_date'
    list_display = ('name', 'creation_date', 'open', 'random', 'deadline')
    inlines = [PeerReviewGroupInline]
    fieldsets = (
        ('Project eigenschappen', {
            'classes': ('extrapretty', 'wide',),
            'fields': ('name', 'open', 'random', 'deadline'),
        }),
        )
```

But i can't see how this makes any display look different. The admin page looks the same with or without those 2 classes. So what is their use exactly?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/) : "Two useful classes defined by the default admin site stylesheet are `collapse` and `wide`. Fieldsets with the collapse style will be initially collapsed in the admin and replaced with a small “click to expand” link. Fieldsets with the wide style will be given extra horizontal space."

Try to replace `extrapetty` by `collapse` on your example and see what's happen.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the full answer to your question, but `wide` is adding an extra space, for sure.

`extrapretty` might be a way to play around with the CSS in admin. try to go [here](https://coderoad.ru/9874936/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-Django-fieldset-html) and check if this will help. It's not in english, but it might give you some idea